# String literal with trailing whitespace in Rust

Tags: rust

For a test I need a string literal with trailing whitespace, like this (dots are spaces).

```rust
let expected = "
foo....a
.......b
.......
.......c
.......d
";
```

Unfortunately editors commonly strip trailing whitespace. Good in general, so I don't want to require people to disable it, but it breaks this code.

Is there a *nice* way to specify this string in such a way that it has the same value but doesn't have trailing whitespace in the code? By nice I mean it doesn't look too different from the existing code.

This is the best I can come up with:

```rust
let expected = "
foo....a
.......b
.......\
\n.......c
.......d
";
```

It's not great but I can't think of anything better. You could use something like `format!(".....{s}", s="...")` but that seems worse.

Comment: Which editor changes whitespace within a string?

Comment: VSCode, but I imagine most of them do.

Comment: If most of them do, then perhaps you can prepare a demonstration in a Rust playground?

Comment: @hkBst I can confirm it does - trimming off whitespace at the end of a line. I presume the editor itself is not clever enough to know that the line is actually part of a string literal.

Comment: Use `\x20` instead of a space? Alternatively, `concat!("several ", "string ", "literals")`.

Comment: @k314159, I cannot reproduce that, which is why I asked for an example.

Comment: For most editors, it can be configured whether they strip trailing whitespace when saving. VS Code does not have this setting enabled by default, but it's common that people enable it (I do); same for Emacs.

Comment: There is no general solution. There may be a solution per editor, so you should clarify what editor you're asking about, but it's unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Caesar this is a nicer solution!

```rust
let expected = "
foo....a
.......b
......\x20
.......c
.......d
";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do exactly what you used here on stackoverflow,
and just use dots:

```rust
let expected = "
foo....a
.......b
.......
.......c
.......d
".replace(".", " ");
```

If this weren't test code, and you really needed the string to be constant, you could use the [lazy_static](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/1.4.0/lazy_static/) crate.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if Rust optimises this away since `replace()` isn't a `const fn`. But yeah in a test it doesn't matter. This is a nice solution if the string doesn't contain `.` anywhere (and I guess you can use a different character if it does). Thanks!

Comment: I tested that before claiming it of course: https://godbolt.org/z/9Gdha1Pf7
The output is quite messy, but look for the example::compare.
LLVM constant folding is quite amazing. EDIT: it seems my first quick glance was wrong. It actually does allocate. Hm, unfortunate.

Comment: I think you might be misreading it. Still looks like it does the replace at runtime to me. Compare with [these functions](https://godbolt.org/z/5jTxG3EeP).

Comment: And also note the call to `core::str::pattern::StrSearcher::new()`.